# Submit Button Not Responding When Clicked

Tags: html, forms

I have this form, but the submit button does not seem to respond.

```
<form id="contact-form" action="exec.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
              <label><span class="text-form">Name:</span>
                <input name="p1" type="text" />
              </label>
              <label><span class="text-form">Email:</span>
                <input name="p2" type="text" />
              </label>
              <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="text-form">Message:</div>
                <textarea></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="buttons"> <a class="button-2" href="#">Clear</a> <a class="button-2" href="exec.php">Send</a> </div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
```

Comment: instead of <a> tag use <input type="submit"> button tag

Comment: Replace the <a>..</a> Tag with <input type="submit" value="Send" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use buttons instead of links.

```
<button type="reset" class="button-2">Clear</button>

<button type="submit" class="button-2">Send</button>
```

Comment: I appreciate all the answers. Considering the fact that I am a newbie, this answer is easier for my understanding and worked too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the anchor tag:

```
<a class="button-2" href="#">Clear</a>
<a class="button-2" href="exec.php">Send</a>
```

Use this following button tag:

```
<button type="reset" class="button-2">Reset</button>
<button type="submit" class="button-2">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function get_form( element )
    {
        while( element )
        {
            element = element.parentNode
            if( element.tagName.toLowerCase() == "form" )
            {
                //alert( element ) //debug/test
                return element
            }
        }
        return 0; //error: no form found in ancestors
    }
    //]]>
</script>
<form name="form" id="contact-form" action="exec.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <label><span class="text-form">Name:</span>
            <input name="p1" type="text" />
        </label>
        <label><span class="text-form">Email:</span>
            <input name="p2" type="text" />
        </label>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="text-form">Message:</div>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons"> 
            <a class="button-2" href="#">Clear</a> 
            <a class="button-2" onclick="get_form(this).submit(); return false">Send</a> </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="button-2" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit(); return false;">Send</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Submit the form explicitly using the following code:

```
<a class="button-2" href="exec.php" onclick ="javascript:this.submit();">Send</a>
```